# How to substitute external library dependencies with internal module in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-recyclerview

I have used many libraries in my project.

I have recently edited and rewritten the recyclerview library and added "androidx.recyclerview.widget" as a module, but I get the following error when building:

```
Program type already present: androidx.recyclerview.widget.AdapterHelper$Callback
```

The reason for this error is that a number of external libraries are dependent on the recyclerview library.
RecyclerView library package name is "androidx.recyclerview.widget" and my recyclerView package name is "androidx.recyclerview.widget" and this is what causes this error.

**I am looking for a solution to tell Gradle to replace all external library recyclerview with my recyclerview module in all dependency.**

I have tried to replace this with the command below but still get the same error

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    resolutionStrategy {
        dependencySubstitution {
            substitute module('androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0') with project(':recyclerview')
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: export recyclerView from the dependencies?

Comment: i have replace all recyclerview library in project with my recyclerview module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the problem, just add it inside build.gradle (Module: app)

```
android {
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'androidx.recyclerview', module: 'recyclerview'
}
```

}